# ThreadPoolExecutor works, but ProcessPoolExecutor not

Tags: python, parallel-processing, future

Using Python 3.7.1, this works just

```
with concurrent.futures.ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers = 2) as executor:
    print("Exec")
    result = executor.map(lambda a: kernel(**a), params)
```

also working

```
for p in params:
    kernel(**p)
```

`kernel` returns a dict and does some computational intensive stuff. It uses no global variables. params contains user-defined classes, but `pickle.dumps(params)` returns no errors and a byte-string.

The file itself is importable, i.e. has the `if __name__ == "__main__": main()` at the buttom.

If I use a `ProcessPoolExecutor` however, the execution stalls. `Exec` is printed, nothing more. CPU load is idle.

I would prefer to the Process model to get around the GIL.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Answering my own question, an older Python version gave me a hint:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/multiprocessing/queues.py", line 241, in _feed
    obj = ForkingPickler.dumps(obj)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/multiprocessing/reduction.py", line 50, in dumps
    cls(buf, protocol).dump(obj)
AttributeError: Can't pickle local object 'main.<locals>.<lambda>'
```

So I took the lambda expression out of the map, and now it also works with ProcessPoolExecutor.